# Compare the runtime of the movies with the maximum runtime of all the movies using SQL windows function

Tags: sql, window-functions

There is a table **movie**.

| movie | year | runtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Titanic | 1999 | 240 |
| Avengers | 2000 | 300 |

**The question is -**

Compare the runtime of the movies with the maximum runtime of all the movies using SQL windows function.

I can't see any scope of using window functions in this, but at the same time, this question is not getting solved with simple queries.

Comment: You can compute the maximum runtime either with aggregation or with window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a RDBMS, so I'll use SQL Server for my example.

```
with movie (
  movie,
  year,
  runtime
) as (
  select *
  from (
  values 
    ('Titanic', 1999, 240)
  , ('Avengers', 2000, 300)
  ) a (movie, year, runtime)
)
select movie
  , year
  , runtime
  , max(runtime) over (partition by 1)
from movie
```

Comment: Even ```select 
movie, 
year, 
runtime, 
max(runtime) over (partition by 1)AS 'Max Run Time'
from movies;``` works the same

Comment: That would only work if you have a table named "movies".  You said your table is named "movie".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work...

```
with max_runtime as (
  select max(runtime) as runtime from movie
)
select m.movie, m.year, m.runtime, mr.runtime - m.runtime as diff
from movie m
  join max_runtime mr
    on 1=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(runtime) FROM tableName) AS Max_Runtime
FROM tableName
ORDER BY movie DESC
```